# "Ходить по струнке" - что это значит буквально?

Tags: фразеология

Как возник фразеологизм "ходить по струнке"?

Answer (score 1):

Есть реже употребляемая идиома "ходить по нитке". И струна и нитка предполагаются туго натянутыми. То есть шаг влево, шаг вправо приравниваются к побегу.

[Струна = натянутая нить (плотник рубит по струне).](http://www.endic.ru/michelson/Po-strunke-hodit-7805.html)

> Все въ струнѣ, по стрункѣ ходить (иноск.) - въ строгомъ порядкѣ, безъ
>   уклоненій (какъ держатся направленія по натянутой струнѣ).

**[По ниткѣ ходить](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_old/6802/%D0%9F%D0%BE)** (иноск.) -

> быть въ строгомъ послушаніи (намекъ на протянутую нитку, которой
>   слѣдуетъ держаться, не уклоняясь отъ направленія ея).
>
> *У меня... пикнуть не смѣли, по ниточкѣ ходили. Не давалъ я вашей сестрѣ зазнаваться* (Островскій. Воспитаница).